# lua-nginx must be run as root

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

I have a simple lua-nginx conf of this style

```
  server {
  server_name payment.mybackend.fr
              payment.mybackend.fr;
  set $rails_root /home/deploy/api/MAP;
  set $env 'cloud';

  location ~ /(paypal|paybox_system) {
   content_by_lua_file $rails_root/lib/nginx-redis-payment/$1.lua;
  }
}
```

When I run nginx without sudo, with my current user, the lua script is never called and so the payment is not validated.

When I run it with sudo, it works perfectly.

How can I make nginx don't use root privileges to execute my lua scripts?

Comment: You want something strange. Nginx is almost always runs as `root`. When you start it as non-root it will listen to port 8080 and will not have access to other user's files.

Comment: I start it with a user named "deploy" on port 80, and it's fine. Anymore, the lua script is also owned by this user which has all permissions on these scripts.

Comment: Does the script not *run* at all or does it fail to do its job? What does the script do? Do you get any errors from nginx or the script?

Comment: I'd like to see some sort of strace wrapper around the lua execution if possible.  or at least some error_log style output.

Comment: This script is here to manage the callback from paypal or paybox. I will add some error logs today.

Comment: @Quentin91360, ping.  we still don't see any logs.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your nginx itself runs without `sudo`, just not executing the scripts in question...

This is likely related to the lua scripts in question, and have not much to do with nginx.

I would troubleshoot as follows:

1. Make sure nginx itself runs without `sudo`.  You could use `pkill nginx` and/or `pkill -KILL nginx`, followed by `pgrep nginx` to make sure that no nginx instances are presently running.  Then execute `nginx` without root to make sure it starts up and keeps on running.
2. Try to execute the script under the same user as the one you use to run nginx.  If this fails, provide us with the errors and any possible logs generated, as well as `id` and `ls -la` of the files and directories in question.
3. Look further into any possible logs that nginx as well as the scripts generate when they fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have permission to post a comment on your answer, so my apologies if this answer should belong in the comment section instead as answer.
I experienced something similar a while ago, and I came up with an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593747/idea-for-reload-restart-apache-from-php-script-without-running-as-root 
The idea is the same: you don't want to run Nginx as root for security reasons, but you really want to execute some pre defined commands as root. With a non root script (let's say you put a php script at your location "/(paypal|paybox_system) ") so it can write to a watch folder, the daemon (which runs as root) then gets a signal and executes a root commando (for example running your lua script as sudo).